# How to make a .py file to .exe from Ubuntu to run it on Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, exe

I have made a python script using python3.5, it uses many packages like tkinter, matplotlib, pylab etc. I want to convert .py file to .exe so that I can give it to people to run on windows. However I need to do the following conversion from Ubuntu only.

Comment: Have you tried pyinstaller?

Comment: I tried it but after making the exe it does not open up on windows

Comment: Are you making it a console based app? If yes, have you tried running the exe file from inside a Windows console window?

Comment: No not a console based app. It should run by doubleclicking on the exe file(dependencies may or may not be,not a problem with that part).

Comment: By console based app, I meant is it a GUI based app or without GUI?

Answer (score -1):

in my opinion its not possible to create some executables in linux for windows